# Is the phrase "un poco de" an example of partitive?

Tags: preposiciones

Following the discussion related to the question [Use of the preposition ''de''](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/15377/11155), I want to ask a separate (but strongly related) explicit question:

**Is the phrase *un poco de* an example of *[partitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partitive)* in Spanish?**

It seems to match the definition of partitive as

> a word, phrase, or case that indicates partialness...  In many languages  the partitive is expressed by the genitive case, sometimes called the partitive genitive.

Comment: [Apparently it is a "cuantificador"](http://elcastellano.elnortedecastilla.es/castellano/aula/un-poco-de).

Comment: According to the RAE , only numbers (un, dos, tres) or such (medio, tercio, tercera parte...) are _partitivos_. 'De' is described as part of a _construcción partitiva_ here (http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=XEVeLzVZaD6CG25cW5), but not as a partitive itself. Personally, I'm not a fan of translating grammar terms because each language tends to describe others using as a model their own conceptions of language or structures. Thus, several English sources describe 'de' as a partitive, while the RAE doesn't recognize it as such. So it may be a _partitive_, but not a _partitivo_.

Comment: And *is* it a partitive or not? :) I understand your dislike but such constructions help a lot to understand foreigners some constructions which seem completely strange to them in their own language. Such as "why should I use *de* if nothing like this is required in my language in the same place".

Comment: In that case, yes, it is.

Comment: @Yay ....so you should convert your comment in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the RAE, only numbers (un, dos, tres...) or such (medio, tercio, tercera parte...) are *partitivos*. 'De' is described as part of a *construcción partitiva* here (lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=XEVeLzVZaD6CG25cW5), but not as a partitive itself. Personally, I'm not a fan of translating grammar terms because each language tends to describe others using as a model their own conceptions of language and sentence structures. Thus, several English sources describe 'de' as a partitive, while the RAE doesn't recognize it as such. So it may be a *partitive*, but not a *partitivo*.

However, note that this question is not the same as the one being discussed in the original thread. There, 'de' was claimed to be a partitive, which is not true in Spanish. 'Un poco de' is indeed a partitive (or a *construcción partitiva* in Spanish), but not *de* itself.

Interestingly, other languages closely related to Spanish do consider *de* as a partitive. The main difference between Spanish and other Romance languages such as Italian or French is that Spanish *de* in *un poco de* is a genitive preposition, but French *de* in *Je veux de l'eau* or Italian *di* in *Voglio dell'acqua* are not so because the genitive case is described as "a noun modifying another noun" and there's no noun to modify in *Je veux de l'eau* or *Voglio dell'acqua* (*eau/acqua* being the "another noun"). That noun is required in Spanish, but not in French or Italian. Actually, in those languages they aren't even called a preposition because a preposition "links", and there's nothing to link in *Je veux de l'eau/Voglio dell'acqua*.

That's why French and Italian call it a partitive article and consider it more or less as a part of the noun itself, not as a connection between the noun/verb and the noun. So the "object" of I want is *de l'eau/dell'acqua*, not that *de/di* connects want and water, as is the case in Spanish *Quiero un poco de agua*, where *de* connects "poco" y "agua", thus being a real preposition rather than an article. That's what makes them essentially different, both sintactically and morphologically, and there lies the difference between a 'genitive case' and a 'partitive'.